# Styling owl carousel videos

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'd like to style the video play button and hide the scrubber, etc but I'm not sure where this default skin is being pulled from.

```
<div>
    <video id="example_video_3" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="auto" poster="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/528578639_640.jpg" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor amet">
    <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/134888075?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" type='video/mp4' />

    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
    </video>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLz17fcv/8/

Answer (score 0):

In your code have this:

```
<p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
```

That led me to this part...

http://videojs.com/getting-started/#skinning